# Select specific row with between and preceding clause

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am working on a table

```
Date     name     value
20110201  xxx     1.2
...
20110201  yyy     1.3
```

I want to calculate the average of value for each name in 2011 July only. Here is my code.

```
select a.name, avg(value) 
over (partition by name Range  between 31  
preceding and XXX) average
From table a
```

Where XXX is the row of where '20110731' for each name. How to complete XXX part please?

PS: Because July has 31 days, so make an average from July 31 back 31 days in the analytic function should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need analytic functions to do this. You can simply do the following:

```
SELECT a.name, AVG(a.value)
  FROM mytable a
 WHERE a.mydate LIKE '201107__' -- I'm assuming you're storing the date as a VARCHAR2
 GROUP BY a.name;
```

(As a side note storing the date as a character column is bad practice.)

Note the wildcard character `_` I'm using in the subject of the `LIKE` operator. It matches a single character.

Another way of doing this might be as follows:

```
SELECT a.name, AVG(a.value)
  FROM mytable a
 WHERE TO_DATE(a.mydate, 'YYYYMMDD') BETWEEN DATE'2011-07-01' AND DATE'2011-07-31'
 GROUP BY a.name;
```

That is, convert the date to a `DATE` and handle it appropriately. I've used `BETWEEN` above, even though I've recommended against it elsewhere, because these dates won't have a time portion to be concerned about.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. David. I ask this question because I have another question like this.

Comment: Thanks David. I ask this question because I have another question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28748431/analytic-function-and-select-specific-row

Answer (score 1):

May be you can use subquery?

```
select a.name, (select avg(value) from table where name=a.name and trunc(date,'mm')='01-jul-2011') average
From table a;
```